# DataGrid which does not resize on AddingNewItem Event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm a newcomer and really don't know how to solve this kind of problem. I do have a `UserControl` with `Ribbon` on top and `DataGrid` underneath. It opens up as a new window after user's click. The actual problem is that `DataGrid` is updating every constant period of time, for instance, every second, new row appends, and because of that the height of a window is changing to fit the content and stops growing only when it reaches the bottom of the screen.

XAML file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Aean.Commissioning.Views.JournalingServiceView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Aean.Commissioning.Properties"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="600"
         Background="White"
         Margin="0,5" x:Name="journalingServiceView">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Ribbon x:Name="ribbonPanel" Grid.Row="0"
            Focusable="false" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" 
            ContextMenu="{x:Null}" ShowQuickAccessToolBarOnTop="False">

        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

        <RibbonTab x:Name="journalingServiceTab" Tag="JournalingServiceView"
                   ContextMenu="{x:Null}"
                   Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Journals}">
            <RibbonGroup UIElement.Uid="DiscoveryOperations"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBoolConverter}, 
                         FallbackValue=False, TargetNullValue=False}"
                         UseLayoutRounding="True"
                         HeaderedItemsControl.Header="Overview" ContextMenu="{x:Null}">
                <RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
                    <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                        <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="true"/>
                        <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="true"/>
                    </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                </RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>

                <RibbonButton UIElement.Uid=""       Label="{x:Static p:Resources.DownloadConfig}"               
                              Command="{Binding GetJournalsCommand}"
                              LargeImageSource="/assets/download.png"    Style="{StaticResource AeanButtonStyle}" />
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>

    <DataGrid x:Name="journalDataEntries" Grid.Row="1"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              UseLayoutRounding="True"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding JournalDataEntries, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group ID" Binding="{Binding GroupId}" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message Type ID" Binding="{Binding MessageTypeId}" Width="90"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Object ID" Binding="{Binding ObjectId}" Width="80"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

In my opinion it's unacceptable and I tried to solve this problem by binding the height of `DataGrid` to the height of window ([link #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232675/wpf-binding-the-height-of-a-component-to-anothers) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742513/auto-height-in-combination-with-maxheight)). It's not working out well. I can't set size as a ratio, 'cause it will change the height of a `Ribbon`, it must be like a fixed navbar and does not change it's height, so this is also not a solution ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678194/in-wpf-how-do-i-make-a-datagrid-fit-the-window-height), none of these answers worked out for me). After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566752/11889079) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10995075/11889079) answers I tried to put all of the information inside `StackPanel` but the problem persisted.

So the final question is: "Is it possible to create grid which will not resize on `AddingNewItem Event` and will occupy the rest of the window.

Source code of ViewModel in case, if it will be needed.

```
using Aean.Commissioning.Infrastructure;
using Aean.Commissioning.Views;
using Aean.Core;
using DynamicData;
using IO.Swagger.Api;
using IO.Swagger.Model;
using NLog;
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace Aean.Commissioning.ViewModels.Widgets
{
    public class JournalServiceViewModel
    {
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    public int? GroupId { get; set; }

    public int? MessageTypeId { get; set; }

    public int? ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string Val1 { get; set; }

    public string Val2 { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public JournalDataEntry JournalDataEntry => new JournalDataEntry(Id, Timestamp, GroupId, MessageTypeId, ObjectId, Val1, Val2);

    public JournalServiceViewModel() : this(new JournalDataEntry(DefaultId, DefaultTimestamp, DefaultGroupId, DefaultMessageTypeId, DefaultObjectId, DefaultVal1, DefaultVal2))
    {

    }

    public JournalServiceViewModel(JournalDataEntry prototype)
    {
        Refresh(prototype);
    }

    internal void Refresh(JournalDataEntry prototype)
    {
        Id = prototype.Id;
        Timestamp = prototype.Timestamp;
        GroupId = prototype.GroupId;
        MessageTypeId = prototype.MessageTypeId;
        ObjectId = prototype.ObjectId;
        Val1 = prototype.Val1;
        Val2 = prototype.Val2;
    }

    private static string DefaultId => "default";
    private static string DefaultTimestamp => new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString();
    private static int? DefaultGroupId => 0;
    private static int? DefaultMessageTypeId => 0;
    private static int? DefaultObjectId => 0;
    private static string DefaultVal1 => "default";
    private static string DefaultVal2 => "default";
    }

    [WidgetManager(typeof(JournalingServiceView))]
    [Description("Сообщения")]
    [Category("Обмен данными")]
    public class JournalingServiceViewModel : CustomDisplayViewModel
    {
    public HistoryApi API { get; private set; }

    private Dictionary<string, bool> IdLookupTable { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    [Reactive]
    public ObservableCollection<JournalDataEntry> JournalDataEntries { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<JournalDataEntry>();

    public string LastKnownId { get; set; } = null;

    public JournalingServiceViewModel(INetworkCommunicationService dataService) : base(dataService)
    {
        GetJournalsCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(GetJournalDataEntries);

        GetJournalsCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(exception =>
        {
            LocalLog(new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, "", exception.ToString()));
        });
    }

    protected override void CollectModels()
    {
        var connector = new ApiConnector(DataService);
        API = new HistoryApi(connector);
        GetJournalDataEntries();
    }

    public override void Refresh(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Update();
    }

    private async Task GetJournalDataEntries()
    {
        await Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
    }

    private async void Update()
    {
        await Observable.Start(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var a = await API.GetJournalAsync(LastKnownId);
                a.ForEach(x => {
                    if (!IdLookupTable.ContainsKey(x.Id))
                    {
                        IdLookupTable.Add(x.Id, true);
                        JournalDataEntries.Add(x);
                    }
                });
                LastKnownId = JournalDataEntries.Last().Id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> GetJournalsCommand { get; private set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: The user control looks fine, But it will create such a problem depending on how you are using it inside the window, for example, I've created a similar control and put it as direct child of the window and it works.

Comment: This is not the default behavior. By default  `Window` won't resize itself to fit its content. Can you please show how you display the `UserControl`? Do you set the `Window.SizeToContent` property on `Window`? Setting this property e.g. to `Height` will force the `Window` to resize itself.

Comment: Yes, @BionicCode, you're right. The parent `Window` does have `SizeToContent` property and it's value is `WidthAndHeight`.

Comment: Why, are you sure that you need it? Removing at least the height e.g. by setting `Window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Width` will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that out and it works greatly, but there's also another `UserControl` element which needs to be sized correctly. At least, now I now why the `Window` was changing it's height. Thank you very much!

Comment: `Window.SizeToContent` has no influence on child controls. It only affects the resize behavior of the `Window`. If you are not satisfied with the resize behavior of a `UserControl` you  should check its layout and the layout configuration of the parent container e.g., `Grid`.